# Microsoft Graph API Creating Event no longer returning conferenceId

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We have been using the Graph API to create meetings in PHP using the Model\Event::class. It's been fine for many months. As part of the event packet we include onlineMeeting => true.

This would return (as per the Graph API documentation) an onlineMeeting json section in the returned json response properties. This would include (as per the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeetinginfo?view=graph-rest-1.0) various useful bits of information like the toll number and more importantly the conference id for the meeting.

In the last week something seems to have changed and this is not being returned in the response json. onlineMeetings now only includes joinUrl.

Comment: The videoTeleconferenceId comes from the meeting room devices, which are generated for Cloud-Video-Interop licensed users. You will require license for [Get meeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) details API. Could you please check the license?

Comment: a ConferenceID is generated for regular Teams Meetings where external people are invited with the Office 365 Audio Conferencing license which we have. This was working fine and this information was in the API up until last week. The ConferenceID is extractable from the bodyPreview of the event json response. So this is currently my work around. What I am asking is why it is missing from the onlineMeeting json section. As per the documentation that I linked to.The conferenceID is given to users who dial in using the provided Teams telephone number.

Comment: We have the correct licenses we were advised by Microsoft to purchase and, it was working fine! Now something in the API is broken. Please can this be investigated. It is frustrating as a small business to be told via Support Ticket that I am not entitled to API support because we don't pay for it. In order for us to embrace Microsoft technology as a platform I need to know that issue like this don't fundamentally break without notice and as such breaking our customer experience. It working just fine for a good 3 months until last week when suddenly the conferenceid vanished.

Comment: Could you please check license validity?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT can you please stop asking that. Not only have I explained fully that I have the required license but someone below has the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

We're actually experiencing the exact same thing here, last Friday we had one meeting that did return the number and conference ID and the rest going through up to now do not. They only include the meetingURL.

I contacted support and they are submitting a ticket to the Exchange department who handles this API call. I will report back what I hear from them.

Final update: Microsoft has re-added those variables so things should be back to normal!

Comment: That’s great to hear. I was wondering why nobody else was reporting this. Thinking surely it must be widespread. Please let me know if you get any news.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy there is a big difference between an 'Answer' and a 'Solution'. The fact is it, at least, 'answered' my question that it wasn't just me. So yes, it was an answer of sorts and, at the very least, draws attention to this issue.

Comment: @travis-wiese How did you get your ticket escalated? I keep getting told I need to be a premier customer for Graph API support.

Comment: To answer everyone, it wouldn't let me comment or else I would've, apologies. Also for the ticket we have premier support so they called next day and moved it from Teams support to exchange. They noted they use a different API call for Teams, and gave a workaround of retrieving the body preview as it has the details. I'll keep updating here as I get more details and I will post what was provided tomorrow.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert I actually do not have the specific API the Teams Engineer said he uses, but I believe it was to me/onlinemeetings. This wouldn't work for us as we call to users/$userID when we run, which he noted the API call he uses didn't support users.

To elaborate on our workaround, we have the actions go through Power Automate and Logic apps, and grab "BodyPreview" and "joinURL" to hand through for now.

Still no further update from Microsoft on it yet.

Comment: @travis-wiese the key thing to highlight to them is it was working before! So they have changed or broken something sometime after Friday 25th based on your own last successful meeting. I'm using the same workaround of bodyPreview which is working well. However, it would be nice for them to not break stuff and what else will they break in the future? We build systems on the back of this API. It's pretty annoying for company as big as Microsoft to be messing about and breaking API's.

Comment: I have been assured twice they are, but been provided no progress to it unfortunately.

Comment: @traviswiese what are Microsoft playing at? Have you noticed they have now broken the bodyPreview? My system failed yesterday to extract the Conference ID because they have messed up the layout. This is so unprofessional that they keep breaking this.

Comment: @chrisherbert I did notice that, and I actually brought it up to them, when we noticed it that they not only broke our main function, but our backup as well. They noted the details are still in the full body parameter, but there's so much clutter in there I would need to parse that data out, so ours still sits broken for now unfortunately

Comment: @traviswiese I actually successfully broke it out of the body parameter. I'd share my code but it's so hacky i'd be embarrassed to share it.

Comment: @chrisherbert That's alright! Sometimes my code is the same way, nothing to be embarrassed about! Knowing someone else got it, I may give it a try as well. Unfortunately mine is all through logic apps/flow which I'm not fluent in, but it should be doable. In the meantime I will update my post still on any updates from Microsoft regarding this.

Comment: @traviswiese I'm really quite astonished there aren't more people complaining. This clearly breaks the API spec as per their documentation. Surely there must be thousands of people relying on this API all over the world? How can this have not been noticed? Are we seriously the only ones who rely on capturing the conferenceId from the API? Seems to me like this would be quite a popular API call. I just don't get it. Thanks for keeping us updated.

Comment: @traviswiese It's now fixed! Thank you for all your help pushing this.

Comment: @chrisherbert Of course! Hope I did speed things up some, I just got the official call from them regarding it. Just need to change my code back to looking for those.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert Is this working for you both? I'm not getting a conference Id or a toll number on either a create or a get call

Comment: @varunsingh I just confirmed mine is still returning those details for meetings since I am licensed with an audio conference license.

Comment: @VarunSingh yes mine is still working. Do you have an audio conference license?

Comment: @ChrisHerbert and Travis, thanks for responding! Yes you are both correct, it's because we don't have an audio conferencing license. Confirmed that it's working for me with the license.