# Graph API Not Returning conferenceId

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

We made a call to create a calendar event but it's not returning the conferenceId back per the example provided in "Example 4: Create and enable an event as an online meeting on". We're only receiving the joinUrl back.

```js
"onlineMeeting": {
    "joinUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_NzIyNzhlMGEtM2YyZC00ZmY0LTlhNzUtZmZjNWFmZGNlNzE2%40thread.v2/0?context=%7b%22Tid%22%3a%2272f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47%22%2c%22Oid%22%3a%22bc55b173-cff6-457d-b7a1-64bda7d7581a%22%7d",
    "conferenceId": "177513992",
    "tollNumber": "+1 425 555 0123"
}
```

Link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Are we missing any parameters to pass on to the API?

Comment: We have raised a bug for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ongoing issue for us too. It was working and is supposed to return in the format you say. Now it does not. See [Microsoft Graph API Creating Event no longer returning conferenceId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123465/microsoft-graph-api-creating-event-no-longer-returning-conferenceid)

It's really frustrating. I had been extracting the conferenceID from the bodyPreview but as of yesterday they broke that too.

Comment: Chris. Have you reached out to Microsoft Premier Support for this issue.?

Comment: @MichaelChaiwimol We don't have Premier Support. If you click on the other thread I linked you will someone there has and has an ongoing ticket open with Microsoft.

Comment: Microsoft has confirmed that it's fixed. Check out this post - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10457

Answer (score 0):

I posted an issue on GitHub and Microsoft Dev team has resolved the issue. We tested and confirmed that the issue has resolved.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10457