# O365 API not returning Conference ID and Toll Number for Teams Meetings

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Per this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-calendar-online-meetings?tabs=http), when creating an event it should return

```
"onlineMeeting": {
    "joinUrl": "https...",
    "conferenceId": "291633251",
    "tollNumber": "+1 323-555-0166"
}
```

I am instead receiving:

```
"onlineMeeting": {
    "joinUrl": "https...",
}
```

I get the same issue when getting an existing event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Seems related to this question, but this issue is not fixed for me: [Microsoft Graph API Creating Event no longer returning conferenceId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123465/microsoft-graph-api-creating-event-no-longer-returning-conferenceid)

Comment: We are not able to repro the issue at our end. Could you please share the error message?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT There is no error message. The reason I wasn't getting the data is because we don't have an audio conferencing license. This should be specified in the docs, I don't believe it mentioned this anywhere. Also I think the the better solution may be to return "null" in this case.

Comment: Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/device-capabilities/native-device-permissions?tabs=desktop) - You need to enable the audio permissions in teams app to get audio access. To get the conference id and toll number you need to get license for VTC please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/cloud-video-interop-for-teams-set-up) for more info.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Thanks for your help. I still think it's worth mentioning, in the API docs (the first link I posted), why certain fields would not be returned. New developers to the office APIs will start there, and if certain fields are not being returned and it's not specified in the API doc, it's not clear why that's the case.

Comment: we will update the docs. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this issue is recorded as fixed. Kindly retry creating an event and if you are able to reproduce the issue, the team will revisit the issue. Thank you

Comment: It is not working as intended, that's why I opened this question.

I am sending a POST to "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events"
with json: "{'isOnlineMeeting': True, 'onlineMeetingProvider': 'teamsForBusiness'}"

And am getting back:
{
   ...
    'onlineMeeting': {'joinUrl': 'https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3ameeting_Njd...'}
}

Comment: To be clear, I'm currently able to reproduce this issue.